# Sending PHP array to Javascript Array via JSON and JQUERY autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have fully functioning jquery autocomplete code. I am trying to pass some of the elements of the returned array to a javascript array and in turn fill out a value from DIV ID.

I modified the code as advised by SCX in the comments below (Thanks so much SCX) but we are not quite there yet. Here is the modified code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#edit-ad-location').autocomplete({
                source:'/postcodes-latlong.php',
                minLength:2,
                response: function( event, ui ) {
                   //ui have response from you call
                   //console.log(ui);
                   //assign your values like this
                   $('#geo-search-lat').val( ui[0]['geo-search-lat'] );
                   $('#geo-search-lng').val( ui[0]['geo-search-lng'] );
                }
    });
});
```

This returns the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geo-search-lat' of undefined
```

I should have mentioned that the array can contain many record entries and not just one.

```
{"0":
      {"id":"384047",
       "label":"4503, DAKABIN",
       "value":"4503, DAKABIN",
       "geo-search-lat":"-27.226474",
       "geo-search-lng":"152.980732"},
   "1":
       {"id":"384062",
        "label":"4503, GRIFFIN",
        "value":"4503, GRIFFIN",
        "geo-search-lat":"-27.272654", 
        "geo-search-lng":"153.025911"},
    "2":
        {"id":"384077",
         "label":"4503, KALLANGUR",
         "value":"4503, KALLANGUR",
         "geo-search-lat":"-27.25075",
         "geo-search-lng":"152.992606"},
     "3":
       {"id":"384092",
        "label":"4503, KURWONGBAH",
        "value":"4503, KURWONGBAH",
        "geo-search-lat":"-27.225828",
        "geo-search-lng":"152.947552"},
   "4":{
        "id":"384107",
        "label":"4503, MURRUMBA DOWNS",
        "value":"4503, MURRUMBA DOWNS", 
        "geo-search-lat":"-27.258672",
        "geo-search-lng":"153.006916"},
    "5":{
        "id":"384122",
        "label":"4503, WHITESIDE",
        "value":"4503, WHITESIDE",
        "geo-search-lat":"-27.255364",
        "geo-search-lng":"152.929729"
        }
 }
```

So I tried modifying SCX's two beautiful lines of code like this:

```
  $('#geo-search-lat').val( ui[]['geo-search-lat'] );
  $('#geo-search-lng').val( ui[]['geo-search-lng'] );
```

and also like this:

```
  $('#geo-search-lat').val( ui['geo-search-lat'] );
  $('#geo-search-lng').val( ui['geo-search-lng'] );
```

But neither of these work.

So let's say if for instance from the autocomplete pull down menu I select 4503, KALLANGUR,, the associated 'geo-search-lat' and 'geo-search-lng' array elements would be:

`ui[2]['geo-search-lat']` and `ui[2]['geo-search-lng']`, correct?

This is my train of thought behind removing the ui[0] and replacing it with ui[] - but this doesn't work.

I need some way to send the record number 'x' to the ui['x'].

TIA.

Comment: Looking at your array, you may need to use `myArray[0]['geo-search-lat']`.

Comment: There are 2 problems, one how he used his array and second that he dont know that autocomplete call is asynchronous so myArray do not have data until its returned from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get the correct syntax and make my code work. I had to change the name returned from the JSON for 'geo-search-lat' and 'geo-search-lng' to 'latitude' and 'longitude'. It appears that the jQuery ui.item.geo-search-lat and ui.item.geo-search-lng were failing because of the hyphens.

Here is the working code to obtain a jquery array object's value from the label:

```
     <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#edit-ad-location').autocomplete({
                    source:'/postcodes-latlong.php',
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#geo-search-lat').val( ui.item.latitude );
                        $('#geo-search-lng').val( ui.item.longitude );
                    }
        });
});
    </script>
```

This autocomplete call returns the correct values in the `<div id="geo-search-lat">` and `<div id="geo-search-lng">`, as well as auto-populating the `<div id="edit-ad-location>` menu with data from the database.

It took some time but I finally got there! Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it inside your autocomplete call, I think [response](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) event will be best for that.

```
$('#edit-ad-location').autocomplete({
                    source:'/postcodes-latlong.php', 
                    minLength:2,
                    response: function( event, ui ) {
                       //ui have response from you call
                       //console.log(ui);
                       //assign your values like this
                       $('#geo-search-lat').val( ui[0]['geo-search-lat'] );
                       $('#geo-search-lng').val( ui[0]['geo-search-lng'] );
                    }  
 });
```

If you want to know why your code is not working take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests):